# Express is sending an object with an object inside

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an Express server which is hooked up to Mongoose db (my terminology might not be correct, as I have just started learning Express). When I access an /admins (route?) I receive an object with my JSON object inside.

Am I sending something incorrectly?

```
 var userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, trim: true},
  lastName: {type: String, trim: true},
  classYear: Number,
  email: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true, trim: true},
  phone: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true},
  phoneProvider: {type: String, trim: true},
  isAdmin: {type: Boolean, index: true},
  isSuperAdmin: {type: Boolean, index: true},
  hash: String,
  companyName: {type: String, trim: true},
  interests: [String],
},
  {
    toObject: { getters: true },
    timeStamps: {
      createdAt: 'createdDate',
      updatedAt: 'updatedDate'
    }
  }
);
```

Part of the admins.js

```
exports.createAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof req.body.email !== 'string')
        return res.status(400).send('Missing email');
    if (typeof req.body.password !== 'string' && typeof req.body.hash !== 'string')
        return res.status(400).send('Missing password');
    if (typeof req.body.companyName !== 'string')
        return res.status(400).send('Missing companyName');
```

req.body.email returns as undefined. The JSON being received is like:

```
{ '{\n\temail:'an@email.com'}': ''}
```

Here's my route to /admins:

```
app.post('/admins', admins.createAdmin);
```

Here's my middleware:

```
app.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  if (!id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/))
    return res.status(400).send('Invalid ID');

  next();
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code sending the POST request as well as how you've configured express itself (ie what middleware you have)

Comment: Most likely the client is submitting JSON as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'application/json'.

Comment: where is the code by which you are sending request?